# Unable to destroy activity,IllegalStateException:activity has been destroyed android fragments

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services

I have created a project where a webservice is called to return a list of colleges in a listview.On clicking a specific college, a new fragment activity containing two fragments are shown.The first fragment contains details in textview and a map.The second fragment contains news details of the specific college.When i press back from the fragment activity(containing two fragments), i get the error in the title.

The fragmentmain.java

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;




import com.igloo.classes.College_data;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class FragmentMain extends FragmentActivity {
    LinearLayout footer;
    Button btndetails,btncollegenews;
    College_data college_item;
    Fragment fr;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        footer=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);
        btndetails=(Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btndetails);
        btncollegenews=(Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btncollegenews);
        college_item= (College_data) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("college_data");

//      Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("college_data",college_item);

        final CollegeDetails fragobj1=new CollegeDetails();
        fragobj1.setArguments(bundle);

        final NewsDetails fragobj2=new NewsDetails();
        fragobj2.setArguments(bundle);

                if(!isFinishing())
                {
                fr=fragobj1;
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr); 
                 fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                 fm.executePendingTransactions();
                 //fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }

         btndetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override


            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        if(!isFinishing())
                        {
                            try{
                        fr=new CollegeDetails();
                        fr.setArguments(bundle);
                         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                         android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr);     
                         fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                         //fragmentTransaction.commit();
                         fm.executePendingTransactions();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                    }



            }
        });
         btncollegenews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(!isFinishing())
                        {
                        fr=new NewsDetails();
                        fr.setArguments(bundle);
                         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                         android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place,fr); 
                         fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                         fm.executePendingTransactions();
                         //fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }

                    }
                });





    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try{
        finish();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The first fragment CollegeDetails.java

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.igloo.classes.College_data;
import com.igloo.classes.News_data;
import com.igloo.collegefinder.CollegeMain.RetrieveColleges;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CollegeDetails extends Fragment {

    TextView txtcollegename,txtcollegeaddress,txtcollegepho,txtcollegelatitude,txtcollegelongitude,txtcollegeimage,txtcollegenews;
    String college_name,course_name;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String URL="http://footballultimate.com/finder/index.php/api/collegeDataWithoutFilter";
    HttpResponse response;
    String result,news_value="";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray college_data;
    College_data college_item;
    Bundle b;
    View v;
    FragmentManager fragManager;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
     // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.college_details, null, false);

        txtcollegename=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtcollegename);
        txtcollegeaddress=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtcollegeaddress);
        txtcollegepho=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegepho);
        txtcollegelatitude=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegelatitude);
        txtcollegelongitude=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegelongitude);
        txtcollegeimage=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegeimage);
        txtcollegenews=(TextView)v. findViewById(R.id.txtcollegenews);
        //college_item= (College_data)getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("college_data");
        college_item=(College_data) getArguments().getSerializable("college_data");


        txtcollegename.setText(college_item.collegename);
        txtcollegeaddress.setText(college_item.collegeaddress);
        txtcollegepho.setText(college_item.collegephone);
        txtcollegelatitude.setText(college_item.collegelatitude);
        txtcollegelongitude.setText(college_item.collegelongitude);
        txtcollegeimage.setText(college_item.collegeimage);
//      for(News_data item : college_item.news_list){
//          news_value=news_value+item.news+" ";
//      }
//      txtcollegenews.setText(news_value);

         try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (InflateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
         myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
             fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
//          mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
//            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
//                     getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//             fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
//             fragmentTransaction.commit(); 

            googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();



        }
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         // latitude and longitude
            double latitude =Double.parseDouble(college_item.collegelatitude);
            double longitude =Double.parseDouble(college_item.collegelongitude);

            // create marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(college_item.collegename);
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);




           // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);





            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),12.0f));

            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() 
         {
            super.onDestroyView(); 

                Fragment fragment = (fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
                FragmentTransaction ft = (myContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(fragment);
               ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                //ft.commit();

            }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f.isResumed()){ 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The second fragment NewsDetails.java

```
package com.igloo.collegefinder;

import com.igloo.classes.College_data;
import com.igloo.classes.News_data;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsDetails extends Fragment {
    View v;
    TextView txtnewsfinal;
    College_data college_item;
    String news_value="";
    @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_details, null, false);
        college_item=(College_data) getArguments().getSerializable("college_data");

        txtnewsfinal=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtnewsfinal);
        for(News_data item : college_item.news_list){
            news_value=news_value+item.news+" ";
        }
        txtnewsfinal.setText(news_value);


        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    }
    }
```

The LOGCAT:

```
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.igloo.collegefinder/com.igloo.collegefinder.FragmentMain}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2676)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2694)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1376)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:578)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at com.igloo.collegefinder.CollegeDetails.onDestroyView(CollegeDetails.java:168)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1705)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1007)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1932)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:335)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-14 19:31:25.664: E/AndroidRuntime(22537):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: so what is your question

Comment: How do i prevent it from force closing, when i go back to the page containing the list of colleges.Why does it force close, that is my question...

Comment: You look to be removing a Fragment from a View that no longer exists. `CollegeDetails.onDestroyView()`. What is it you are trying to do there?

Comment: Previously there was a error where when i went to the second fragment and came back to the first, it would crash, so when i added the code in onDestroyView(), it stopped, should i remove it now?

Comment: I removed the onDestroyView and that seemed to have solved the problem.

Comment: I would be a bit suspicious of that method yeah. You should be handling Fragment states by creating Fragments with a `newInstance()` method and reading in values from the Bundle in `onCreateView()` or similar so that the fragment backstack can do its job properly without you needing to manually control it. Give it a Google, loads of tutorials on it.